# Primes dividing Fibonacci mod 4

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to do the following question and am a bit stuck. Would appreciate a hint over a full solution if possible. Here $F_n$ denotes the $n$-th Fibonacci number, and at this point in the question we have already shown $F_{2n}=F_n(F_{n-1}+F_{n+1})$ and $F_{2n+1}=F_n^2+F_{n+1}^2$ for all $n \ge 1$.

Given $m \ge 1$ and $p$ an odd prime dividing $F_m$ determine whether the following statements are true or false:

1. if $m$ is odd, then $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$
2. if $m$ is even, then $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$

My line of thinking so far: I know (by Fermat's little theorem) that $x^2 \equiv -1 (\text{ mod p})$ has a solution iff $p \equiv 1  \pmod 4$. So if I
 can find such an $x$, or show none exist, then I am done. Especially in the $m$ odd case, by writing $m=2n+1$ we have $F_n^2+F_{n+1}^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ which implies $(F_n+F_{n+1})^2 \equiv -2F_nF_{n+1} \pmod p$. But I don't see how to progress any further on that front and have a feeling I'm going down a rabbit hole. My other thought is that since p is odd, we know $p$ must be congruent to one of $1$ or $3 \bmod 4$, so we can try and get a contradiction by assuming one or the other. No luck here either.

Comment: The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) on the Fibonacci numbers asserts claim 1 as a fact, but provides no proof.   They provide [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#CITEREFLemmermeyer2000) as a reference for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original idea is solid.

The first claim follows from [Cassini's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities):  $$F_n^2=(-1)^{n+1}+F_{n-1}F_{n+1}$$

To see this, suppose $n+1$ is odd and that $p$ is an odd prime dividing $F_{n+1}$.  We instantly get that $$F_n^2\equiv -1\pmod p$$ and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

We have $F_{10}=55$ for $m=10$. Since $p=5$ divides $F_{10}$, but $5\not\equiv 3\bmod 4$, statement $2.$ is false.

Statement 1. is proved in Lemma 2 [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&ved=2ahUKEwiiv4urnIvpAhXRzaQKHWJdBZcQFjAKegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fq.math.ca%2FScanned%2F8-1%2Fdaykin-a.pdf&usg=AOvVaw14rQCUWia8juDNypkwPMAJ) - if I understood correctly. Note that it implies that every Fibonacci number $F_{2n+1}$ is the sum of two squares by Fermat's result.

Comment: Thanks for the counter example, did you have a way of narrowing down or did you just evaluate every $F_m$ (as luck would have it I stopped after $m=9$)? Also any luck on statment 1?

Comment: This is late but for future readers, since $F_{2n} = F_n(F_{n+1} + F_{n-1})$ then if $p$ divides $F_n$, it divides $F_{2n}$. Then for some odd $n$ there is a prime of the form $4k+1$ which divides $F_n$ and hence also divides $F_{2n}$. A good way to find this counterexample is then to find some odd n such that a prime of the form $4k+1$ divides $F_n$. $F_5 = 5$ so 5 divides $F_{10}$ even without calculating.